# Sharing user preferences in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, key-bindings, jetbrains-ide

Is there an easy way to switch between user profiles for PyCharm?

Basically, my colleague and I have different preferences especially for keybindings, and we'd like to switch between preferences gracefully while pairing. It be nice to include themes and fonts too.

It's fine to do one dump and then load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can each `File > Export Settings...`

Then when you switch do `File > Import Settings` and navigate to your personal settings file.

Should do all the things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Settings Sync plugin that is not bundled with the IDE at the moment (you can get it from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9922-ide-settings-sync). 
It keeps your user preferences (UI and editor themes, keymaps, and the list of enabled and disabled plugins) in the cloud and lets you sync with them when you switch to your JetBrains Account. 
In your situation the workflow would be as follows:

1. Sync with account 1
2. When you need to switch, disable local sync and close the IDE
3. Switch to account 2 in the Toolbox App
4. Start the IDE and enable sync